# Passing arguments to flask.url_for()

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a simple website where the user uploads an image, which is then displayed on the page. In get_root:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_root():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template("webpage2.html", image = upload_file())
    return render_template("webpage2.html")
```

In upload_file:

```
@app.route('/upload/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'fileToUpload' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['fileToUpload']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
```

In uploaded_file():

```
@app.route('/image/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

When I test it out the page loads, but without the image, and I get the following error on the console:

```
TypeError: uploaded_file() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I've tried a number of variations, but this seems to me the main problem: passing the correct parameter to uploaded_file.

Comment: Could you post both the routes w/ the decorator in your question?

Comment: i.e. the full definition of both `get_route` and `upload_file` w/ `@app.route` decorator

Comment: Also where are you using `url_for`? You referenced it in the question title but I don't see it anywhere in your question.

Comment: If it's in the same `blueprint`, try to use `url_for('.uploaded_file', filename=filename)`, as stated here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for 
If that still doesn't work, please provide more information Adam requested